# Compiler Error CS0016 in creating XML Documentation File

Tags: asp.net-core

I get: `Compiler Error CS0016. Could not write to output file 'file' — 'reason'. The compiler could not write to an output file. Check the path to the file to make sure it exists. If a previously built file is already at the location, make sure it is writeable, and that no process currently has a lock on the file. For example, make sure your executable is ...`

How to keep the project path for the xml file fixed in a asp.net core application

[image]

Comment: Do you run the application in a Docker Container?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

### How to handle xml documentation

1. **Check the checkbox on your screenshot and set the path** (the path should get set automatically when checking the checkbox). As the error message suggests: If there is already a file under that path which is write protected delete it manually.

   - as alternative you can set it in the `.csproj` (your project file) like:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DocumentationFile>[Replace with absolute Path to your Projectfolder/[Assembly Name].xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

2. Access path in your `Startup.cs`:
   In `ConfigureServices` do somethiong like:

```cs
            var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
            var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
```

Comment: I tried that with checking the checkbox , but It get changed time to time..  Is there a other way that I can keep it fixed from the visual studio?

Comment: When you write it manually to project file? When (what are you doing) did it get changed? Normally this setting is **persistent** (fixed)